# Show div on href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, href

I have an href link that shows this on error:

```
'You are not verified yet, Please enter the verification code. <strong><a href="#" class="sms-code-field">Click here</a> to enter verification code</strong>'
```

Also, I have this JavaScript that's being called when "CLICK HERE" is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        var inserted = false;
        $('#login_error').on('click', '.sms-code-field', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if(!inserted) {
                var html = '<p><label for="sms_code">Verification Code<br />';
                html += '<input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" value="" tabindex="25" />';
                html += '</label></p>';

                $('p.forgetmenot').before(html);
                inserted = true;
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I want to change the script to show this div on click:

```
<div class="sms-code-field" style="display: none;">
  <label  for="inputSMSCODE"><?php echo $CORE->_e(array('login','10')); ?></label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
       <input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" > 
    </div>              
</div>
```

and please note that the div i want to show is populated from another page
but the error and the div appears on the same page.
removing the style="display: none; using the browser debugger the div appears.

Comment: `<label  for="inputSMSCODE"><?php echo $CORE->_e(array('login','10')); ?></label>`

does that have the correct information in it at the same time that the link appears to click? or does this need to be run after?

Comment: i think it have the correct info, as from chrome debugger if i deleted style="display: none; it shows correctly

Comment: then any of the answers below should give your desired result :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply to set `$('.sms-code-field').show()` in the onclick function

Comment: You already have a function for the click event. Just put the code in there.

Comment: you mean like this ?                 $('#login_error').on('click', $('.sms-code-field').show(), function(e){

Comment: you might have to do it this way `$('div.sms-code-field').show();`

Comment: at the onclick you should an `a` like the `div` above

Comment: still not working, does it matter if the div i want to show is on another php page??

Comment: seems on the way you include it

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an `onclick` attribute to the `a` tag and then input the JS neccessary to show the div inside the attribute quotes. That should fix the problem relitively simply.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just add `$('.sms-code-field').show();`

**Note** that if you have more than one `.sms-code-field` element and want to show a specific one, we will need to see more of your `html`

**Also note** that you did not show us an element with `id="login_error"` so I have added my own below as it is needed for your code to work. Show us all of your `html` if this doesnt fix your problem

```js
(function($) {
    var inserted = false;
    $('#login_error').on('click', '.sms-code-field', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sms-code-field').show(); // added this line
        if (!inserted) {
            var html = '<p><label for="sms_code">Verification Code<br />';
            html += '<input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" value="" tabindex="25" />';
            html += '</label></p>';

            $('p.forgetmenot').before(html);
            inserted = true;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login_error"> 'You are not verified yet, Please enter the verification code. <strong><a href="#" class="sms-code-field">Click here</a> to enter verification code</strong>'
  <div class="sms-code-field" style="display: none;">
    <label  for="inputSMSCODE">php output here</label>
    <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to delete this i think its causing issue of not showing. var html = '<p><label for="sms_code">Verification Code<br />';
            html += '<input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" value="" tabindex="25" />';
            html += '</label></p>';

Comment: You dont show us a paragraph element with the class `forgetmenot` so it's hard to test that part, if this solution doesnt work it's because we need to see all of your `html`

Comment: ignore the forgetmenot, even if deleted it doesn't affect the code, its a check box

Comment: can you better explain what you need the code to do and where this solution fails to accomplish that? If so, we can help fix it

Comment: the error message appears when the user try to login, the user have to active his account, so when he try to login, the error message appears, and supposedly if the "CLICK HERE" is click, it will show another box to input the sms code, which is the div.

Comment: So `.sms-code-field` is shown by some other function and you want this `<p><label for="sms_code">Verification Code<br /><input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" value="" tabindex="25" /></label></p>` to appear when the link is clicked?

Comment: yes somehow, but i dont want this to appear i want the div <div class="sms-code-field" style="display: none;">
to appear instead

Comment: I dont understand, the above solution makes `<div class="sms-code-field" style="display: none;"> ` appear right now, if that is what you want then what is the issue?

Comment: the issue is that it doesn't work, please note that the div i want to show is populated from another page but the error and the div appears on the same page. removing the style="display: none; using the browser debugger the div appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.sms-code-field').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sms-code-field').css('display','block');    
  });
});
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tokusaqofa/1/

Comment: still don't work, does it matter if the div i want to show is on another php page?

Comment: @AhmedNabil have you checked out the demo?

Comment: Sure it does. In that case you may need [tag:ajax].